# Linux Mint 16: Petra - Can't wake from hibernate

Tags: linux-mint, suspend, hibernate

I have used Linux Mint 16 Petra - cinammon version for a few months. At first hibernate worked pretty well. Now I cannot wake from it - when I try to, the screen just goes blank and nothing responds and I need hard reboot.

Here are some commands from suggestions from another thread (ask me if you need more info):

`uname -a`:

```
Linux bartoszkalinowski-PC 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller 
           X.Org: 1.14.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Desktop GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.1
```

I use Intel graphics HD4000 I think (i5 3570K) - maybe the case is with graphic drivers? I tried installing them manually but I've read they are included in the kernel and there shouldn't be any trouble with this integrated graphics card.